# Generating random session id whenever user uses login() in web services

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

Am new to web services. Am trying to generate unique session id for every login that a user does, in web services. 
What I thought of doing is,

1. Write a java file which has the login and logout method.
2. Generate WSDL file for it.
3. Then generate web service client(using Eclipse IDE), with the WSDl file which I generate.
4. Use the generated package(client stub) and call the methods.

Please let me know if there are any flaws in my way of implementation.

**1. Java file with the needed methods**

```
public String login(String userID, String password) {
    if (userID.equalsIgnoreCase("sadmin")
            && password.equalsIgnoreCase("sadmin")) {
        System.out.println("Valid user");
        sid = generateUUID(userID);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Auth failed");
    }
    return sid;
}

private String generateUUID(String userID) {
    UUID uuID = UUID.randomUUID();
    sid = uuID.toString();
    userSessionHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    userSessionHashMap.put(userID, sid);
    return sid;
}

public void logout(String userID) {
    Set<String> userIDSet = userSessionHashMap.keySet();
    Iterator<String> iterator = userIDSet.iterator();
    if (iterator.equals(userID)) {
        userSessionHashMap.remove(userID);
    }
}
```

**2. Generated WSDL file**

3. Developed the web service client from the wsdl.

**4. Using the developed client stub.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ClientWebServiceLogin objClientWebServiceLogin = new ClientWebServiceLogin();
    objClientWebServiceLogin.invokeLogin();
}

public void invokeLogin() throws Exception {
    String endpoint = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/";
    String username = "sadmin";
    String password = "sadmin";
    String targetNamespace = "http://WebServiceLogin";
    try {
        WebServiceLoginLocator objWebServiceLoginLocator = new WebServiceLoginLocator();
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(endpoint);
        Iterator ports = objWebServiceLoginLocator.getPorts();
        while (ports.hasNext())
            System.out.println("ports Iterator size-->" + ports.next());

        WebServiceLoginPortType objWebServiceLoginPortType = objWebServiceLoginLocator
                .getWebServiceLoginHttpSoap11Endpoint();
        String sid = objWebServiceLoginPortType.login(username, password);
        System.out.println("sid--->" + sid);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("AxisFault at creating objWebServiceLoginStub"
                + exception);
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On running the this file, I get the following error.

```
AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode: 
faultString: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:        connect
```

Can anyone suggest an alternate way of handling this task ? And what could probably be the reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Web services are supposed to be stateless, so having "login" and "logout" web service methods doesn't make much sense.

If you want to secure web services calls unfortunately you have to code security into every call. In your case, this means passing the userId and password to every method.

Or consider adding a custom handler for security. Read more about handlers [here](https://www.packtpub.com/article/handler-and-phase-in-apache-axis).

Comment: But I've heard there is something called 'Stateful WebServices'. Will that be helpful, if yes, how can it be implemented ?

Comment: See this article. http://wso2.org/library/articles/stateful-web-services-axis2. It seems like a lot of trouble to me :)